# Encrypt SQL Server Database Structure

Tags: sql-server, encryption

I'm working with my team to build a web application for our customers that uses ( ASP.Net & MSSQL ), we need to encrypt the Database structure to avoid stole the database design.

is't any way to do that, and how ?

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

No, is not possible. You are asking for DRM and SQL Server does not offer any DRM. Any claim to the contrary is snake oil. You simply cannot hide secrets from an local administrator, it will **always** be able to locate any secret.

If you want to protect IP you must not distribute it to the client, use a cloud based solution.

Comment: thanks for answer, is't any Database that supports this ' DRM ' ?